# Apple Mail won't send annotations on images for any other Image Size than "Actual Size"

Tags: macos, mail.app, screen-capture, markup

macOS: 13.0 (22A380)

A lot of communicating with my clients depends on annotated screenshots I send them via Email. My workflow goes like this:

1. I press <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>, then I press <kbd>space</kbd> and click the window that I want to take a screenshot of. This saves a screenshot of the selected window in my clipboard.
2. I open Mail, create a new message and paste the screenshot I just took
3. I add annotations to the screenshot, like circles around important parts in the screenshots
4. I send the message to my clients.

Today I learned these annotations don't make it to my clients if I have selected any other "Image Size" rather than "Actual Size". The annotations also don't show up in my outbox.

**Will send the image with annotations:**

[image: image size actual size]

**Will send the image without annotations:**

[image: image size large]

Does anyone else have this problem and maybe even a solution?

...I just found out that if I don't use the clipboard but instead save the screenshots to disk first, it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to send something that at that point exists only in RAM.
That's why you need to save it first.

Perhaps Mail ought to be smart enough to temporarily save this somewhere - & who knows, current versions of Ventura may have fixed that, you never know, but you're still on the buggy beta RC 13.0.0 build. Current is 13.1

Comment: Why does it work then if I select "Actual Size"? The image still comes from the clipboard

Comment: Presumably, it can just paste; as it doesn't have the annotations either, this would be a reasonable assumption. I think you've just found something that was never meant to work, but there's sufficient system-wide functionality already that it 'half works.